# adding new methods to established classes

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I would like to extend the list functionality, so we can used as below. How can add this methods to the list object?

```
  # list([1,2,3,4,5]).even() should return [2,4]
```

Comment: You can't (well, without rewriting Python's source code).  You're better off subclassing `list`.

Comment: You could do somersaults, maybe the good point is to point to the following .

Comment: You can [add](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object) methods to objects though.

Comment: @Marcin But not to lists, because they are implemented in C.

Comment: You can either subclass `list` or create a utility function that takes the list and manipulate it the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't monkey patch `list` because it is defined in C extension modules and is therefore inmutable in this sense. You can subclass list:

```
class mylist(list):
    def even(self):
        return [x for x in self if x % 2 == 0]

>>> mylist([1,2,3,4,5]).even()
[2, 4]
```